# 'render' is not defined no-undef in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-bootstrap

I already made component.
I am gonna use forms-validation(react-bootstrap) in my component.
When I made this forms in my component, I got  the error like:

> 'render' is not defined no-undef'

**Code:**

```
import react, {Component} from 'react';

export defaults class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {....}
  }

   render() {
     return(
       <div></div>
     )
   }
}

function FormExample() {
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    setValidated(true);
  };

return(
  <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  ....
  </Form>
 );

 render(<FormExample />);
}
```

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation

this is forms-validation I used.

please advice any suggestions:

Comment: Hi, your code has two `render()` methods and am sure the error identifies a specific `render()`. Please tell us which one. But there are two issues you need to resolve first. I suspect there is a typo while declaring the class; remove the "s" from **defaults**. Secondly, `FormExample` is a functional component, which don't have `render()` methods. So remove that. I think this might actually solve the error.

Comment: @MwamiTovi
did you check this?
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation
then how can i import this component in my existing component?

Comment: Notice that in the example code you are referring to that the last `render(<.../>)` is NOT within the component (it's on it's own). The authors are using that last `render()` to show you how you can render that component after being imported. Otherwise, you can import it like any other `react` component.

Comment: @MwamiTovi
i am not sure what you mean.
can you show me some example with codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: It's exactly what @khabir has stated in his answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have used `functional component` for `FormExample` and `functional component` does not use `render` function instead, `class component` supports `render` function. `Functional component` uses return statement that works like render. So please remove the below line from `FormExample`.

```
render(<FormExample />);
```

here is the code after removing render:

```
function FormExample() {
  const [validated, setValidated] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }

    setValidated(true);
  };

return(
  <Form noValidate validated={validated} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  ....
  </Form>
 );
}
```

Comment: but seeing this
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation
there is render in functional component.
also i have component in my code.
if so, how can i implement this form-validation in my existing component?